# <Windows.h> c++ threads and inheritance

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, inheritance

Hello guys I'm working on  a Thread class and a CountingThread class inherated from Thread class including Synchronized Counter using  library. But while creating this CountingThread class I'm having a problem of "incomplete type is not allowed"  So i would be happy if you give some advise if I'm forming this Thread abstract class in a bad structure or say what am I doing wrong. (FYI i have to keep classes and methods because it's an assignment)

```
#ifndef _THREAD_H_
#define _THREAD_H_

#include <Windows.h>
#include <iosfwd>

class Thread{
private:
    HANDLE hThread;
    int idThread;

public:
    Thread(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE fnct){  // here I'm trying to get a function and create thread with it
        hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0,fnct,NULL,0,(LPDWORD)&idThread);
    }

    virtual void main()=0;

    void suspend(){
        SuspendThread(hThread);
    }
    void resume(){
        ResumeThread(hThread);
    }
    void terminate(){
        TerminateThread(hThread,0);
    }

    static void sleep(int sec){
        Sleep(sec*1000);
    }

};


#endif
```

CountingThread.h

```
#ifndef _COUNTINGTHREAD_H_
#define _COUNTINGTHREAD_H_

#include "SynchronizedCounter.h"
#include "Thread.h"

class CountingThread :public Thread{
private:
    SynchronizedCounter counter;
public:
    CountingThread(counter.increment()){   // here I'm having the error "incomplete type on counter"
    }    // I want to create thread with the counter.increment function

};

#endif
```

SynchronizedCounter.h

```
#ifndef SYNCHRONIZEDCOUNTER_H_
#define SYNCHRONIZEDCOUNTER_H_

#include "Mutex.h"
#include <iosfwd>

class SynchronizedCounter{
private:
    int count;
public:
    SynchronizedCounter();
    SynchronizedCounter(int);
    void increment();
    int value();
    friend std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream& output, const SynchronizedCounter& counter)
    {
        output << counter.count << endl;
        return output;
    }
};

#endif
```

and synchronizedCounter::increment

```
void SynchronizedCounter::increment(){
    Mutex mut;
    mut.lock;
    count++;
    mut.unlock;
}
```

Comment: What should that line of code even do? A function call cannot be part of a function declaration

Comment: "Thread class and a CountingThread class inherated from Thread class" - and that's a requirement of the assignment? In modern C++, a threading API is not designed in terms of class inheritance. Just look at the design of C++11 threads (`std::thread` and friends).

Comment: Should not 'virtual void main()=0;' be overridden in descendant classes?

Comment: Just in case that is your issue (your question is a bit vague...), at the time that the baseclass constructor is invoked, the actual type of the object (used for resolving virtual functions) is that of the baseclass! Only later, it changes its type to the derived class. Still, consider Chritian Hackl's response, you are not doing yourself a favour with this approach at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to to be a syntax error.  You should define an argument here :

So it should be:

```
class CountingThread :public Thread{
private:
    SynchronizedCounter counter;
public:
    CountingThread()
        {
        counter.increment())
         //... etc
        }    // I want to create thread with the counter.increment function
//...
};
```

Anyway as counter.increment() returns void, you cannot pass it as parameter.

Comment: Guess the problem is my constructor of Thread.h  because this is the way i create a thread as i know. because Thread doesnt have a default constructor i cant use CountingThread() without parameters. So I'll create threads in my descendant classes